# Confused with \begin{minipage}

Tags: minipage

I want this:

[image]

So I wrote:

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \alert{\textbf{2nd order Picture}}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item \begin{math}
          \mathcal{L}^{2nd}_{0} = -\frac{1}{2}\bar{\mathcal{F}}_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{F}^{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
           J^{1 \mu} = \frac{i\alpha}{2}[-\mathcal{F}_{\mu \nu}\bar{B}^{\nu}+\bar{\mathcal{F}}_{\mu \nu}B^{\nu}]
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
          \mathcal{L}^1_{Int} = J^{1 \mu}A_{\mu}
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
           J^{2 \mu} = \alert{-\alpha^2 \bar{B}^{\nu}B_{\nu}A^\mu} [\alert{the \ seagull - like \ vertex}]
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
           \mathcal{L}^2_{Int} = J^{2 \mu}A_{\mu}
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
           \mathcal{L}^{2nd} = -\frac{1}{2}(D_{\mu}B_{\nu}-D_{\nu}B_{\mu})^{*} (D^{\mu}B^{\nu}-D^{\nu}B^{\mu}) - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}
      \end{math}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}\hfill

  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \alert{\textbf{1st order Picture}}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item \begin{math}
           \mathcal{L}_0^{1st} = \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} + \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{P}^{\mu \nu} + \bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{F}^{\mu \nu}
      \end{math}
      \begin{math}
 \mathcal{Q}_{\mu \nu}\bar{\mathcal{F}}^{\mu \nu}+\bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{Q}^{\mu \nu}
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
          J^{1 \mu}=i\alpha[-\mathcal{Q}_{\mu \nu}\bar{B}^{\nu}+\bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}B^{\nu}]
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
          \mathcal{L}^1_{Int} =  J^{1 \mu}A_{\mu}
      \end{math}
      \item \alert{\begin{math}
          \mathcal{L}^{1st} =  \mathcal{L}^{1st}_0 +   \mathcal{L}^1_{Int}
          \end{math}
          \begin{math}
          = \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} + \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{P}^{\mu \nu} + \bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}(D^{\mu}B^{\nu}-D^{\nu}B^{\mu})
      \end{math}
      \begin{math}
          + \mathcal{Q}_{\mu \nu}(D^{\mu}B^{\nu}-D^{\nu}B^{\mu})^{*}+\bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{Q}^{\mu \nu}
      \end{math}}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
```

But I obtained this:

[image]

Why didn't the minipage separate the text in two columns?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you using the `beamer` document class? Please advise.

Comment: Please extend your example to something others can copy and test as is.

Comment: the result has been resolved by the answer beneath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you care about your readers' abilities to understand the math terms, I think it would be advisable to switch from `enumerate` to `align` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\small
\alert{\textbf{2nd order Picture}}
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}^{\text{2nd}}_{0} 
  &= -\tfrac{1}{2}\bar{\mathcal{F}}_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{F}^{\mu \nu} 
     -\tfrac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} \\
J^{1 \mu} 
  &= \frac{i\alpha}{2}\bigl[-\mathcal{F}_{\mu \nu}\bar{B}^{\nu}+\bar{\mathcal{F}}_{\mu \nu}B^{\nu}\bigr]\\
\mathcal{L}^1_{\text{Int}} 
  &= J^{1 \mu}A_{\mu}\\
J^{2 \mu} 
  &= \alert{-\alpha^2 \bar{B}^{\nu}B_{\nu}A^\mu} \\  
  &\qquad [\alert{\text{the seagull-like vertex}}]\\
\mathcal{L}^2_{\text{Int}} 
  &= J^{2 \mu}A_{\mu}\\
\mathcal{L}^{\text{2nd}} 
  &= -\tfrac{1}{2}(D_{\mu}B_{\nu}-D_{\nu}B_{\mu})^{*} \\
  &\qquad\times(D^{\mu}B^{\nu}-D^{\nu}B^{\mu}) \\
  &\quad - \tfrac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} 
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\small
\alert{\textbf{1st order Picture}}
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_0^{\text{1st}} 
  &= \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} 
    +\mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{P}^{\mu \nu} \\
  &\quad + \bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{F}^{\mu \nu}
   \mathcal{Q}_{\mu \nu}\bar{\mathcal{F}}^{\mu \nu}\\
  &\quad + \bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{Q}^{\mu \nu}\\
J^{1 \mu}
  &=i\alpha\bigl[-\mathcal{Q}_{\mu \nu}\bar{B}^{\nu}+\bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}B^{\nu}\bigr] \\
\mathcal{L}^1_{\text{Int}} 
  &= J^{1 \mu}A_{\mu}\\
\alert{\mathcal{L}^{\text{1st}}} 
  &= \mathcal{L}^{\text{1st}}_0 + \mathcal{L}^1_{\text{Int}} \\
  &= \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} 
   + \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{P}^{\mu \nu}\\ 
  &\quad+ \bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}(D^{\mu}B^{\nu}-D^{\nu}B^{\mu})\\
  &\quad + \mathcal{Q}_{\mu \nu}(D^{\mu}B^{\nu}-D^{\nu}B^{\mu})^{*}\\
  &\quad + \bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{Q}^{\mu \nu}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

The empty line between your minipages forces latex to start a new paragraph -- which will be in a new line.

Don't want to start a new line? Don't add an empty line :)

(and please have a look at the comments by @David Carlisle and @barbara beeton about alignment issues)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
      \alert{\textbf{2nd order Picture}}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item \begin{math}
          \mathcal{L}^{2nd}_{0} = -\frac{1}{2}\bar{\mathcal{F}}_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{F}^{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} 
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
           J^{1 \mu} = \frac{i\alpha}{2}[-\mathcal{F}_{\mu \nu}\bar{B}^{\nu}+\bar{\mathcal{F}}_{\mu \nu}B^{\nu}]
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
          \mathcal{L}^1_{Int} = J^{1 \mu}A_{\mu}
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
           J^{2 \mu} = \alert{-\alpha^2 \bar{B}^{\nu}B_{\nu}A^\mu} [\alert{the \ seagull - like \ vertex}]
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
           \mathcal{L}^2_{Int} = J^{2 \mu}A_{\mu}
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
           \mathcal{L}^{2nd} = -\frac{1}{2}(D_{\mu}B_{\nu}-D_{\nu}B_{\mu})^{*} (D^{\mu}B^{\nu}-D^{\nu}B^{\mu}) - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} 
      \end{math}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
      \alert{\textbf{1st order Picture}}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item \begin{math}
           \mathcal{L}_0^{1st} = \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} + \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{P}^{\mu \nu} + \bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{F}^{\mu \nu} 
      \end{math}
      \begin{math}
 \mathcal{Q}_{\mu \nu}\bar{\mathcal{F}}^{\mu \nu}+\bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{Q}^{\mu \nu}
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
          J^{1 \mu}=i\alpha[-\mathcal{Q}_{\mu \nu}\bar{B}^{\nu}+\bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}B^{\nu}]
      \end{math}
      \item \begin{math}
          \mathcal{L}^1_{Int} =  J^{1 \mu}A_{\mu}
      \end{math}
      \item \alert{\begin{math}
          \mathcal{L}^{1st} =  \mathcal{L}^{1st}_0 +   \mathcal{L}^1_{Int} 
          \end{math}
          \begin{math}
          = \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} + \mathcal{P}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{P}^{\mu \nu} + \bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}(D^{\mu}B^{\nu}-D^{\nu}B^{\mu})
      \end{math}
      \begin{math}
          + \mathcal{Q}_{\mu \nu}(D^{\mu}B^{\nu}-D^{\nu}B^{\mu})^{*}+\bar{\mathcal{Q}}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{Q}^{\mu \nu}
      \end{math}}
      \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}%

\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: answers the question, but looks horrible, I'd use `[t]` not `[b]` or `[c]` so the top headings align.

Comment: Since some of the lines go to more than one column, you really want `\raggedright`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree, but that's the alignment the OP requests in the question

Comment: @barbarabeeton I suspect the OP is using a different page geometry and/or fontsize

Comment: I know, I even voted:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz -- Definitely a different page width and/or font size, but the principle that math shouldn't be allowed to stretch like that is worth observing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Added a note that they should look at both your and David's comments :)